# Creating a for loop to publish multiple CSVs as feature services?

Tags: csv, feature-layer, feature-service, for-loop, arcgis-python-api

I have multiple CSVs that I want to publish them each as unique feature services. Instead of publishing them one at a time, I'm trying to find the correct syntax to create a for loop.

This is the notation I (successfully) used to publish a single layer:

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.geocoding import geocode
gis = GIS("http://slustl.maps.arcgis.com/home", "*username*")
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("thunder_d.csv")
df.head()
csv_file = r'C:\Users\Stephanie\NOTEBOOKS\thunder_d.csv'
csv_item = gis.content.add({}, csv_file)
csv_lyr = csv_item.publish(None, {"Address":"ToLocation"})
```

And this is the start of my attempt to publish multiple using a loop:

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
import os
from arcgis.features.analysis import *
from arcgis.features import FeatureLayer


gis = GIS("http://slustl.maps.arcgis.com/home", "*username*")
data_dir = r"C:\Users\Stephanie\NOTEBOOKS\FINAL\csvs"
file_list = os.listdir(data_dir)

csv_file_list = [x for x in file_list if x.endswith(".csv")]
print("Number of .csv files found: " + str(len(csv_file_list)))
for file in csv_file_list:
```

I'm new to coding so creating loops still can confuse me.

Once I publish the CSVs, could I also create a loop to edit their symbology, or do I have to do that one layer at a time?

Comment: You havent made an attempt with the foor loop. Place the code for your single layer indented after `for file in csv_file_list:` and see what happens. What ArcGIS version do you have?